# Magento 2: How to create a configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I am new to magento and i have created a simple product programmatically from frontend and my question is how can i create a configurable product and link attributes and price and all, what to do, and how to do that?

please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Configurable product programmatically

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setSku('mySku'); // Set your sku here
$product->setName('Sample Configurable Product'); // Name of Product
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
$product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
$product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
$product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
$product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
$product->setTypeId('configurable'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
$product->setPrice(100); // price of product
$product->setStockData(
                        array(
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                            'manage_stock' => 1,
                            'is_in_stock' => 1,
                            'qty' => 999999999
                        )
                    );
$product->save();
```

Now Add an image to product

```
// Adding Image to product
$imagePath = "sample.jpg"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Now to assign associated products of created configurable product

```
$productId = 12; // Configurable Product Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
$attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attributes = array(134, 135); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
$associatedProductIds = array(2,4,5,6); //Product Ids Of Associated Products
foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
    $position++;
    $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
}
$product->setTypeId("configurable"); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
$product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
$product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4); // Setting Attribute Set Id
$product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->save();
```

Comment: hi, can you elaborate this and i want make a user interface for the customers and give the facility to customers to add products

Comment: have you created any functionality to create products by customer ?

Comment: yes i created simple product functionality . but dont know how to do configurable

Comment: have you tried above code to create configurable product ?

Comment: yes but it only created simple product with typeid configurable, not any configure options added in it

Comment: Yes but after creating configurable product you have to assign simple products on that configurable. 
I have already attached code to assign associated products of created configurable product.

Comment: i did assigned and after if i go to admin panel and check if products are assigned or not,, but got no confugurations

Comment: What code you have written for assign products ?

Comment: the above code that u provided me

Comment: have you replaced attribute ids and products ids with yours ?

Comment: yes i already did

Comment: @JayKapoor and Aasim, It only created simple product with type_id configurable, not any configure options added in it. Replaced attribute ids and products ids with mine. Have you find any solution for it?