# Create Configurable Products in Magento 2 Programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, create-product

How to Create Configurable Products Programmatically in Magento 2?
can anyone tell me about the solution to how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try Link:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191130/24878

Comment: You can take help from http://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-complete-guide-to-add-a-product-programmatically/ or https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

Comment: I have trying above code but not working @arushi

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically create configurable products in magnto2

---

//configurable product

```
$configurable_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$configurable_product->setSku('test-configurable');
$configurable_product->setName('test name configurable');
$configurable_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$configurable_product->setStatus(1);
$configurable_product->setTypeId('configurable');
$configurable_product->setPrice(11);
$configurable_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$configurable_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
$configurable_product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
    )
);

$configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(152),$configurable_product); //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
$configurableAttributesData = $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurable_product);

$configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$configurable_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

$configurableProductsData = array();
$configurableProductsData[$simple_product_id] = array( //[$simple_product_id] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
    '0' => array(
        'label' => 'S', //attribute label
        'attribute_id' => '152', //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store
        'value_index' => '193', //value of 'S' index of the attribute 'size_general'
        'is_percent'    => 0,
        'pricing_value' => '10',
    )
);
$configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);

$configurable_product->save();
```

Try with it.

Comment: how to get simple product id? if product is not created

Comment: @MoinMalek First you need to create simple product which assign under configurable one.

Comment: Ok Got it. lets try it

Comment: @MoinMalek Yes sure, I was able to do that, If any query let me know. If you got success please mark yes to my answer. Thanks

Comment: Not working at all

Comment: @MoinMalek Share the issues.

Comment: First of all I create simple product using $productObj->setName('test');
$productObj->setTypeId('simple');$productObj->setAttributeSetId(4);$productObj->setSku('test);$productObj->setWebsiteIds(array(1));$productObj->setVisibility(1);$productObj->setColor(4);$productObj->setCategoryIds(array(3));$productObj->setPrice(17);$productObj->setTaxClassId(0);
$productObj->setWeight(1);$productObj->setStatus(1);$productObj->setStockData(array( 'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 'manage_stock' => 1, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 500));
$productObj->save();echo $simple_product_id = $productObj->getId();

Comment: then simple id  given by script and then call your code to run via simple id 
 product save but product does not associated

Comment: color attribute id is 93 and color value is 4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67704/discussion-between-envision-ecommerce-and-moin-malek).

Answer (score -1):

Part 1: Create the Configurable Product
Step 1: Select the Product Type is Configurable Product
Step 2: Select the Product Template
Step 3: Complete the Required Fields
Step 4: Complete the Remaining Product Details
Step 5: Save and Continue
Part 2: Add Configurations
Step 1: Select the Attributes
Step 2: Enter the Attribute Values
Step 3: Configure the Images, Price and Quantity
Step 4: Generate the Product Configurations
Step 5: Publish the Products
Step 6: Configure the Shopping Cart Thumbnails (Optional)
Step 7: Final, check your result by view the Products in your store

Comment: I want using Programatocally

Comment: may be it's working.i have create only simple product programmatically.